# Dividing long ints in Python returns wrong answer

Tags: python, math, int, long-integer, factorial

In Python, the following code

```
from math import factorial
print factorial(40)/(factorial(20)*factorial(20))
```

prints out 136772786996.

WolframAlpha says that answer is wrong; it should be [137846528820](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40!/%2820!%2a20!%29). 
What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hmm, I get the Wolfram answer. What are you getting for `factorial(40)` and `factorial(20)`? How do those line-up with Wolfram?

Comment: Is somebody on projecteuler today?

Comment: I get the right answer...

    In [4]: factorial(40) / (factorial(20) * factorial(20))
    Out[4]: 137846528820L

What OS / version of python are you using?

Comment: Maybe you could show more of the code (Is there more code?). It seems like something else may be going on here.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The reported error (I don't see a problem either) is 1073741824, or 2^30.  That seems.. suspicious, because 30 is often a magic number in Python integer storage (#if PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT == 30, etc.) I could be convinced that there's a real problem here for some architecture/compiler/build options/phase-of-the-moon configuration.

Comment: factorial(40) and factorial(20) both output the right answer. I'm running this on Codecademy's interpreter, so maybe it's just a bug with that. Here's my full code: http://labs.codecademy.com/MRd#:workspace

Comment: Aw, man.  You have to say things like "I'm running the code through a web-based interpreter" first.  I'd fallen in love with my idea that it was a weird compiler error on some obscure platform, and now it's probably just some interface bug. :-(

Comment: @DSM: I still think this is some bug in the underlying Python interpreter, not in the interface.  Try just about any division involving long integers, like `(10 ** 11) / (10 ** 5)`, resulting in `957049L`.  On the other hand, `(10 ** 13) / (10 ** 5)` works fine.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: could be.  I couldn't get the site to work for me yesterday, but on a different system today I verified that 2**31/2**29 gives 3L, and that's the smallest 2**a/2**b which isn't divisible by 2.  I emailed them; we'll see if they respond.

Comment: @DSM: It seems they are using [Empythoned](https://github.com/replit/empythoned) to compile CPython to JavaScript (via LLVM bytecode).  Cool that this runs *at all*, for this *is* a weird platforim.

Answer (score 3):

Works just fine for me:

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> print factorial(40)/(factorial(20)*factorial(20))
137846528820
```